# Google BigQuery possible to do Case-Insensitive REGEXP_Match?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery I wanted to check for 'confirm' or 'Confirm':

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.PagePath, r'Confirm') or
REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.PagePath, r'confirm'))
```

I am a Perl person and in Perl we do

```
$foo =~ /confirm/i    # case-insensitive
```

Does Google BigQuery have any flags to modify REGEXP_MATCH?  I did not see any examples in their online docs.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`REGEXP_CONTAINS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains) uses [RE2 library](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), so you may use inline modifiers like this:

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.PagePath, r'(?i)confirm') 
                                   ^^^^
```

See RE2 docs:

> `(?flags)`    set flags within current group; non-capturing
>   ...
>                                                                   **Flags**
>   `i`  case-insensitive (default false)
>   `m`  multi-line mode: `^` and `$` match begin/end line in addition to begin/end text (default false)
>   `s`  let `.` match `\n` (default false)
>   `U`  ungreedy: swap meaning of `x*` and `x*?`, `x+` and `x+?`, etc (default false)
>   Flag syntax is `xyz` (set) or `-xyz` (clear) or `xy-z` (set `xy`, clear `z`).

Comment: That's an interesting way to add flags.  I tried it (note I am in the Google Big Query environment, and within this environment I'm using Standard SQL, not Legacy SQL).  So I tried it:            REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.PagePath, r'(?i)Confirm')   but I got this message:  Query Failed
Error: Syntax error: Parenthesized expression cannot be parsed as an expression, struct constructor, or subquery at [30:22]

Comment: [SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) does not support regex. You may [create a UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) though.

Comment: You may always work around the hard-coded cases: `'[cC][oO][nN][fF][iI][rR][mM]'`

Comment: The (?i) does work fine in BigQuery - here is an example: SELECT REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'(?i)confirm'), REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'confirm') FROM (SELECT 'I Confirm that it works' text) can you give your actualy query to see where the error is coming from

Comment: Update, I had made a typo,  the r'(?i)somestring'  works as intended. This works:                                                                                                                  when REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.PagePath, r'(?i)Confirm') then 'XYZZY'

Answer (score -1):

Not as elegant, but I just used this:

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(UPPER(sources), "CLAIMS")
```